Getting ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) from slugify
public function slugify(string $string, array|string|null $options = null): string

    {

        // BC: the second argument used to be the separator

        if (is_string($options)) {

            $separator            = $options;

            $options              = [];

            $options['separator'] = $separator;

        }

 

        $options = array_merge($this->options, (array) $options);

 

        // Add a custom ruleset without touching the default rules

        if (isset($options['ruleset'])) {

            $rules = array_merge($this->rules, $this->provider->getRules($options['ruleset']));

        } else {

            $rules = $this->rules;



this file is vendor/cocur/slugify/src/Slugify.php:100
When i try to submit the form by select a image then giving this error
syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
in server PHP Version 7.4.33, "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0", and Project laravel framework is 8.75. Now can you guide me to fix this issue.

cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable version 8.0 is support with php version 7.4.33 ?


Union types are not supported in 7.4.xx versions. You should upgrade your PHP version to 8.x.
https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types
